# Set size of child items of arc menu

Tags: android, xml, layout

I downloaded arc menu library from https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu.

Here is **arc_menu.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<com.example.arcmenu.lib.ArcLayout
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:childSize="44px"
    custom:fromDegrees="270.0"
    custom:toDegrees="360.0" >
</com.example.arcmenu.lib.ArcLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/control_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/button_option" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/control_hint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

here is **FragmentActivity** :

```
public class FregmentActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
  private static final int[] ITEM_DRAWABLES = {
        R.drawable.button_contact_us_option,
        R.drawable.button_back_bookmark, R.drawable.button_news_option,
        R.drawable.button_product_option,
        R.drawable.button_featured_option,
        R.drawable.button_about_us_option };
ArcMenu arcMenu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    arcMenu = (ArcMenu) findViewById(R.id.arc_menu);

    initArcMenu(arcMenu, ITEM_DRAWABLES);
}

private void initArcMenu(ArcMenu menu, int[] itemDrawables) {
    final int itemCount = itemDrawables.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
        item.setImageResource(itemDrawables[i]);

        final int position = i;
        menu.addItem(item, new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("TAG", "IN ARC MENU");

            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

here is **main.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.vjmceramics"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<com.example.arcmenu.lib.ArcMenu
    android:id="@+id/arc_menu"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    app:fromDegrees="180.0"
    app:toDegrees="270.0" />
```

Whenever I run my project to nexus4 it shows child icons very small.
and shows different size of icon on different device.

Is there any way to set child size as per device runs on???

please help me. Thank you

Comment: You can do that in **ArcMenu.java** (instead of in **arc_menu.xml**). Since you must set the size in **px** instead of **dp**, you must scale the px to dp in code.

Answer (score 0):

1.remove the icons from the drawable folder(ex. drawadle-ldpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi etc. )
2.keep only one copy of the icon (that u want to show) in the drawable-nodpi folder.

note- if the folder is not present in the res directory then create it